# How to initialise WL with jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-live-id

I'm trying to combine JQuery Mobile with Windows Live Connect.

If I trigger my init code with `$().ready(function() { ... });` and look at it with a browser then it works.

If I try to use the debugger then Visual Studio gets caught in a circular dependency, endlessly loading the script for my page and the Live Connect logon page until finally it barfs.

[image]

If I trigger the init code from `$('#divname').live('pagebeforecreate', function (event) { ... });`
then the debugger is ok but the page doesn't work.

Can anyone offer guidance on combining JQM with WLC? A working sample page with a login button, that responds to login by dynamically adding some items to a listview, would have me over the moon - so far this is all I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you post your initialization code? I'm wondering if you are running into some type of race condition.

Comment: I've got it to work just this minute. Unfortunately there's not much between my three attempts, and I don't much like mysteries. If I figure out what was going on I'll post details. This javascript stuff seems a bit fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts to set this up I finally have a project that works, but I'm still trying to work out what made the difference. Without doubt it is some sublety of initialisation sequence. When I find out exactly what, I will update this answer with details and an annotated sample.